# How to display Indic languages on GLCD

Tags: c, unicode, nlp, embedded, glyphicons

I have a file which is read by STM32 and it displays the contents on a GLCD.

It displays the glyphs of the unicode stream even when there are combining characters (e.g. क + ् + त = क्त ). Here it displays क ् त instead of क्त.

I have done some reading on this and found that every font uses a character mapping( cmap table ) to map character encoding ( e.g. Unicode) with the glyphs. I tried writing a cmap table in C for devanagari but it was an extensive list . Is there any logic I'm missing here which will simplify my cmap table or my objective to map unicodes to the glyphs?

Comment: probably you can find tools that make the job for you. Tools that can convert a standard font (ttf ...) to your required type. I this tools does not exist, better to develop it by yourself.

Comment: The use of an STM32 and a GLCD is entirely irellevant but it is the only technical information you have provided.  What is probably more important is the identity of the font rendering or graphics library you are using to render the characters, and what font technoloyy/format is being used.

Comment: "exhaustive list"?  Did you mean "extensive list"?  "exhaustive" probably does not mean what you intended. ([definition](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20%22exhaustive%22)).  If you truely had an "exhaustive" i.e. "complete" list, there would be no problem.

Comment: I'm using a using a GLCD font creation software [link] ( http://www.mikroe.com/glcd-font-creator/ ) where you can create custom fonts and export them as C library. I mentioned STM32 and GLCD coz my objective was not to print it to a console. And sorry it's an extensive list not exhaustive list

Comment: My guess is the library you're using doesn't support combining characters, so you'll have to do that yourself prior to feeding it to the library.  It probably just tries to find a glyph for each each unicode character you pass it, and prints out one for one.   if there aren't THAT many combos, it might not be too hard or too large to write the preprocessor.

Comment: I found a way to use ttf files to display the ligatures, diacritics etc. emWin offers a library to do that. ttf files already have the 'mort' and 'morx' tables (https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6mort.html) which take care of different combinations of the glyphs depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do so some work and I'm not even sure that the code will fit in a stm32, maybe a big one, perhaps. Have a look at https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/HarfBuzz/, it's a text shaper for many languages including indic ones.

Comment: Yeah, exactly! If it was a big one instead of STM32, I could directly use .ttf files (each one approx. 70KB). But now I have to create glyphs for all possible combination cases. The link was very useful in increasing my understanding on what these font files do, thank you.